# WP site after login keeps redirecting to looped url

Tags: wp-admin, urls, wp-redirect

My site Example.com keeps on redirecting to following url
https://example.com/?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%3Fredirect_to%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252F%253Fredirect_to%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fexample.com%25252F%25253Fredirect_to%25253Dhttps%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Fexample.com%2525252F%2525253Fredirect_to%2525253Dhttps%252525253A%252525252F%252525252Fexample.com%252525252F%252525253Fredirect_to%252525253Dhttps%25252525253A%25252525252F%25252525252Fexample.com%25252525252F%25252525253Fredirect_to%25252525253Dhttps%2525252525253A%2525252525252F%2525252525252Fexample.com%2525252525252F%2525252525253Fredirect_to%2525252525253Dhttps%252525252525253A%252525252525252F%252525252525252Fexample.com%252525252525252F%252525252525253Fredirect_to%252525252525253Dhttps%25252525252525253A%25252525252525252F%25252525252525252Fexample.com%25252525252525252F%25252525252525253Fredirect_to%25252525252525253Dhttps%2525252525252525253A%2525252525252525252F%2525252525252525252Fexample.com%2525252525252525252F%2525252525252525253Fredirect_to%2525252525252525253Dhttps%252525252525252525253A%252525252525252525252F%252525252525252525252Fexample.com%252525252525252525252F%252525252525252525253Fredirect_to%252525252525252525253Dhttps%25252525252525252525253A%25252525252525252525252F%25252525252525252525252Fexample.com%25252525252525252525252F%25252525252525252525253Fredirect_to%25252525252525252525253Dhttps%2525252525252525252525253A%2525252525252525252525252F%2525252525252525252525252Fexample.com%2525252525252525252525252F%2525252525252525252525253Fredirect_to%2525252525252525252525253Dhttps%252525252525252525252525253A%252525252525252525252525252F%252525252525252525252525252Fexample.com%252525252525252525252525252F%252525252525252525252525253Fredirect_to%252525252525252525252525253Dhttps%25252525252525252525252525253A%25252525252525252525252525252F%25252525252525252525252525252Fexample.com%25252525252525252525252525252F%25252525252525252525252525253Fredirect_to%25252525252525252525252525253Dhttps%2525252525252525252525252525253A%2525252525252525252525252525252F%2525252525252525252525252525252Fexample.com%2525252525252525252525252525252F%2525252525252525252525252525253Fredirect_to%2525252525252525252525252525253Dhttps%252525252525252525252525252525253A%252525252525252525252525252525252F%252525252525252525252525252525252Fexample.com%252525252525252525252525252525252F%252525252525252525252525252525253Fredirect_to%252525252525252525252525252525253Dhttps%25252525252525252525252525252525253A%25252525252525252525252525252525252F%25252525252525252525252525252525252Fexample.com%25252525252525252525252525252525252F%25252525252525252525252525252525253Fredirect_to%25252525252525252525252525252525253Dhttps%2525252525252525252525252525252525253A%2525252525252525252525252525252525252F%2525252525252525252525252525252525252Fexample.com%2525252525252525252525252525252525252F%2525252525252525252525252525252525253Fredirect_to%2525252525252525252525252525252525253Dhttps%252525252525252525252525252525252525253A%252525252525252525252525252525252525252F%252525252525252525252525252525252525252Fexample.com%252525252525252525252525252525252525252F%252525252525252525252525252525252525253Fredirect_to%252525252525252525252525252525252525253Dhttps%25252525252525252525252525252525252525253A%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252F%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252Fexample.com%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252F%25252525252525252525252525252525252525253Fredirect_to%25252525252525252525252525252525252525253Dhttps%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525253A%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252F%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252Fexample.com%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252F

Comment: You may want to try deactivating all plugins and activate them back one at a time, then see if there's any of the plugins causing the redirection issue. Or switch to a default theme and see if the issue persists.

Comment: sorry for late reply. however it was Ultimate member plugin that caused all the chaos. disabling it solved the problem for some of its useful functionality i choose some different plugin thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for most of the issues like this its a plugin conflict. in my case too it was a plugin. disabling one by one and troubleshooting will solve similar problems